# Crashes in runtime library under Rosetta

Tags: macos, crash, dyld, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

We are seeing mysterious crashes in our app when running on the Apple Silicon machines using Rosetta. The crash is coming from Apple's `runtime` and `dyld` libraries, and always has the same kind of stack, but without much useful information.

- All have the same pattern of 5 stack frames, the bottom being `dyld`, and then 4 in `runtime`, but all just addresses, no idea what symbols are being called
- Sometimes the offset values are the same, other times they are not. When you group them together, we have at least two sets of stacks; but close enough that it appears the same root issue.
- Only these two libraries appear to be loaded, so perhaps it's a crash on launch before things are adequately setup, or something weird happens during the crash and we are only getting a small part of the picture captured in the .crash, or some corruption happens.
- All are in Apple Silicon machines
- Some are on macOS 11, and some on macOS 12, so it's not a Monterey beta issue
- They are all crashing for reason Code Signature Invalid, but this seems unreliable, if indeed we can launch the app afterwards without issue, which appears to be the case (based on log reports we've received).

Here is a typical example (with some app info redacted):

```
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2021-08-06 14:38:06.408 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.5.1 (20G80)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       15000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x0000000106675000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x2

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0x106675000:
    VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)      106671000-106675000    [   16K] r--/r-- SM=NUL  reserved VM address space (unallocated)
--> mapped file                 106675000-107ff9000    [ 25.5M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  Object_id=695dd8f1
    mapped file                 107ff9000-107ffd000    [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  Object_id=6aaf57f1

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffe9ac40 0x7ffdffe96000 + 19520
1   runtime                         0x00007ffdffea3df4 0x7ffdffe96000 + 56820
2   runtime                         0x00007ffdffea35ec 0x7ffdffe96000 + 54764
3   runtime                         0x00007ffdffe9a440 0x7ffdffe96000 + 17472
4   dyld                            0x000000020683f000 0x20683f000 + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000106675000   x1: 0x000000030d81b730   x2: 0x0000000000000218   x3: 0x0000000000000012
    x4: 0x0000000000000004   x5: 0x0000000001984000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000a40
    x8: 0x0000000000000007   x9: 0x0000000000000012  x10: 0x0000000106675fff  x11: 0x0000000100000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x000007d900018601
   x16: 0x00000000000000c5  x17: 0x000000000220bef3  x18: 0x000000030d81b073  x19: 0x000000030d81b730
   x20: 0x000000030d81aa78  x21: 0x0000000106675000  x22: 0x0000000000000004  x23: 0x0000000106675000
   x24: 0x0000000000000003  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x000000030d81ab90  x27: 0x000000020683f000
   x28: 0x000000030d823960   fp: 0x000000030d81aa20   lr: 0x00007ffdffea267c
    sp: 0x000000030d81a9b0   pc: 0x00007ffdffe9ac40 cpsr: 0x20000000
   far: 0x0000000106675000  esr: 0x92000006


Binary Images:
       0x20683f000 -        0x2068dafff  dyld (852.2) <57DB2053-BFD5-3683-97C6-F1DB2A1F1D09> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ffdffe96000 -     0x7ffdffec5fff  runtime (203.58) <52A2E5D0-FAA3-34EF-8BB7-07F73718C034> /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1048K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1048K(100%)
Writable regions: Total=19.8M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=19.8M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8176K        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                       10.5M        1 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)            1132K        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                             288K        4 
__DATA_CONST                        32K        1 
__LINKEDIT                         272K        4 
__TEXT                             816K        2 
mapped file                        4.8G       11 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              4.9G       28 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     4.9G       28
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated. I cannot say for sure this is an Apple issue, as I have no way to reproduce it reliably, either in our app or another. But it seems doubtful it's a bug in our app.

Thank you!

Comment: @JamesRisner Thanks for asking. We have seen this issue multiple times since August 2021 when I posted the question. The app is my company's product. I don't know if any other apps experience this same type of crash. As for OS, I do not know of any crashes on Monterey, the only reports I have are from various versions of Big Sur. But I wouldn't conclude it couldn't happen on Monterey, perhaps our customers on Monterey just haven't hit the crash yet.

Comment: Thanks @JamesRisner for the link and info. I think I'll keep an eye out for crashes coming from Monterey. If we never get any, then hopefully we can conclude the OS upgrade solved things. I cannot speak to the issue of a universal binary.